# Code Igniter + fine-uploader: IE9 and is_ajax_request command

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, internet-explorer, fine-uploader

After integrating fine-uploader script into a new code igniter installation, I have the following problem: IE 9 returns false when using the "if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request())" command.

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('upload');
}

public function upload()
{   
    error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

    if (!$this->input->is_ajax_request())
    {
        die('No direct script access allowed');
    }

    $this->load->helper("qqFileUploader.class");

    $uploader = new qqFileUploader('uploads');
    // Specify the list of valid extensions, ex. array("jpeg", "xml", "bmp")
    $uploader->allowedExtensions = array();

    // Specify max file size in bytes.
    $uploader->sizeLimit = 900 * 1024 * 1024; // 900 Megabytes

    // Specify the input name set in the javascript.
    $uploader->inputName = 'qqfile';

    $uploader->prefix = 'test_';

    // If you want to use resume feature for uploader, specify the folder to save parts.
    $uploader->chunksFolder = 'chunks';
    $result = $uploader->handleUpload('uploads');
    $result['uploadName'] = $uploader->getUploadName();

    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

}

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely expected.  Fine Uploader does not use XHR to upload files in IE 9 and older (since this is not possible).  Instead, we build a form and submit it, targeting an iframe.